# What is the time complexity (big O) of sortedArrayUsingComparator? iOS/OSX

Tags: ios, macos, algorithm

I need to know the time complexity of the 
**sortedArrayUsingComparator** function of the NSArray class. A source would be great since I'm likely to mention it in my bachelor's thesis.
I'm sorting an array of locations by distance to the current location.

The only answer I could find was someone saying it was at least T(n)=O(n) but likely  T(n)=O(n log n)

How would I know for sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By actual trial of NSArray sorting the times are in line with `O(n*log(n))`.

See [blog post](http://zaph.com/blog/?p=1345)

Note that in a comment there is a sort method (PS9110) which is O(n) but is proprietary and patented. The method is quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Well to sort an array you have to at least look at every element which is for sure `O(n)`. There are several mathematical papers which show you that there can't be a better sorting algorithm then `O(n*log(n))` like `Mergesort` for example. Since the comparator implements a `Mergesort` I think the complexity should be `O(n*log(n))` for best,average and worst case.

You can find some information about `Mergesort` here:
[Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

And some article concerning the best sorting algorithm time complexity:
[Sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

I couldn't find the exact implementation of the given method but here is a great article how you can dig deeper in the implementation of Arrays in Objective-C and to have a look at the methods implementation:
[Exposing NSMutableArray](http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/)